# get latest value from jtable cell in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Can someone give an example of question below:
I have a jtable like below

```
plus  |  minus  |   total
  10  |    0    |     10
   0  |    2    |      8
   0  |    3    |      5
```

How can I get the value of latest total(5) so I can use it again in formula 
total=total+plus-minus? Also the value of total will keep updated because of plus and minus will be added continuously.

Comment: sorry the table look funny. Use this one instead:                     plus 10 0 0                                                           minus 0 2 3                                                           total10 8 5

Comment: do people really feel like the have to '-' someone after just one minute of posting? Maybe they are in the middle of fising their formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone give an example of question below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ChangeNotifiersOnEvent extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean runProcess = true;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private javax.swing.Timer timerRun;
    private Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private String[] columnNames = {"Source", "Hit", "Last", "Ur_Diff"};
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data = {{"Swing Timer", 2.99, 5, 1.01},
        {"Swing Worker", 7.10, 5, 1.010}, {"TableModelListener", 25.05, 5, 1.01}};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    public ChangeNotifiersOnEvent() {
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
                if (tme.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                    if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 2) {
                        double dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(2, 1))
                                - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(2, 2));
                        table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 2, 3);
                    } else if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 0) {
                        prepareUpdateTableCell();
                    } else if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 1) {
                        executor.execute(new MyTask(MyTask.UPDATE_TABLE_COLUMN));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(180);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    private void prepareUpdateTableCell() {
        timerRun = new javax.swing.Timer(10, UpdateTableCell());
        timerRun.setRepeats(false);
        timerRun.start();
    }

    private Action UpdateTableCell() {
        return new AbstractAction("Update Table Cell") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 1))
                        - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 2));
                table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 0, 3);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (runProcess) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            changeTableValues();
        }
    }

    private void changeTableValues() {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128) + random.nextDouble(), 0, 1);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(256) + random.nextDouble(), 1, 1);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(512) + random.nextDouble(), 2, 1);

                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 0, 2);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 1, 2);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 2, 2);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private class MyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        private static final String UPDATE_TABLE_COLUMN = "update";
        private String namePr;
        private double dbl;

        MyTask(String str) {
            this.namePr = str;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1))
                    - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 2));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 1, 3);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChangeNotifiersOnEvent frame = new ChangeNotifiersOnEvent();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

.

notice

- required to set proper value for [getColumnClass to Integer, Long or Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)
- proper of ways is only usage of [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) (easiest as override this event in `DefaultTableModel`), there to override `getValueAt()`,
- inside `getValueAt()` only calculate proper formula for desired column
- I'd be disable `JTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);`, otherwise have to [setModelIndex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setModelIndex%28int%29) or  before calculations

Comment: -1 for a) manipulating the model from its listener (that's model responsibility) b) overriding getColumnClass in the view (again, model business) c) invokeLater in done (it's already on the EDT, and any ordering issues are home-brewn due to the incorrect model modification in the listener) d) minor: restricting usability due to developer lazyness <g>

Comment: .. e) sleeping on the EDT f) accessing the model in doInBackground ... old code or why all those glitches? I know you know they are wrong :-)

Comment: huh, are you sure about point e) this isn't true at all `Runnable#Thread` and `public void run() { `, this was there before `SwingWorker` as an `standard`, and still will be there after `SwingWorker` died, still better than black_hole implemented in `SwingWorker`

Comment: darn, no ... I was wrong in e), had worked myself into a state .... sorry. But what about a-d and f? Me misreading also?

Comment: hmmm agreed (a --> d) I'm standard protype of man, remember all interesing posts from last two years, doesn't care about ........,  about f) accessing, whats ??? :-), this is about get value from accesible Object, never heard about "Swing XxxModel can be accesible opnly on EDT", looks like as the same as accesing String value from any of corners from current JVM, changes are invoked from done()

Comment: sigh ... _all_ access (read _and_ write) to components must happen on the EDT - that does include its models, of course (though you might be lucky with the default implementations because their datastructures are Vectors)

Comment: you might be lucky :-) hehehe, then all Java users from Java 1.2 are on my side of river, interesting, never heard about, value and applied methods accesible from JComponents (its model) are always in static modifiers (JVM side in the any of debuger), anyway I will look at it and care about,

Answer (score 1):

Get the value from the table model. getModel().getValueAt(..)

Comment: Will return the wrong value if sorting has been applied or columns rearranged.

Comment: @Audrius: Then table.getModel().getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowIndex), table.convertColumnIndexToModel())

Answer (score 1):

Call [getValueAt(int row, int column)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29). May return null for empty cells. Do not call this on the model as the table row number may not match the model row number if sorting is enabled and applied. Also the table column number may not match the model column number if table columns have been rearranged.