# Java, .setBackground to values in array

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to set a buttons background to a value held in an array, but im getting errors??

one, two and three are JButtons.
(This is only some code that I have to extend later)

```
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
        String[] colors = {"GREEN","WHITE","ORANGE"};
        if(event.getSource() == one){
            String text = "Clicks = " + ++ clicks1 + ". ";
            one.setText( text );           
            one.setBackground(Color.colors[0]);
            two.setBackground(Color.colors[1]);
            three.setBackground(Color.colors[2]);
```

Comment: what are the errors you are getting? Please provide more information.

Comment: What is the error you get, if you get an exception please post it with your question

Comment: stack trace please, and I don't recommend instantiating a new string array every time an action is performed.

Comment: @Reimeus I'm voting for un_delete :-), but nobody can to see your original answer, because is changed under 5min limits, then my un_delete is empty step

Comment: No problem thanks @mKorbel. The problem is solved now anyway. Most annoying when someone downvotes a correct answer as well as very unhelpful for future readers :@

Comment: @Reimeus [why annoyning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15137708/714968), you haven't any own angel, btw this is public forum (SO status disagree with forum), and your answers must corresponding with your users acceptance (-: jokeeee :-)

Comment: @Reimeus she was right, in most of cases, but my lazyness, endless lazyness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that setBackground takes in a color. So what you want to do is this:

```
Color[] colors = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE};
```

Then set the background: `one.setBackground(colors[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

You should provide something like Color.RED to setBackground method, the syntax you use it wrong.
Define an array of Color, not a String array; something like this

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
    Color[] colors = {Color.GREEN,Color.WHITE, Color.ORANGE};
    if(event.getSource() == one){
        String text = "Clicks = " + ++ clicks1 + ". ";
        one.setText( text );           
        one.setBackground(colors[0]);
        two.setBackground(colors[1]);
        three.setBackground(colors[2]);
```